# Woocommerce - Execute code after a user processes payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to execute a function upon successful payment in Woocommerce.

For example, when a user makes a purchase and clicks the payment button, it would return successful.

I then want to call a function.

How would I accomplish this? Is there a filter I can use in **functions.php?**

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

For additional context, my function would contain an API call so if a user successfully makes a payment, it would call an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "woocommerce_payment_complete" hook, which is fired when the payment is complete.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'do_something_after_payment_complete' );
function do_something_after_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: always good to check the status of the order  (($order->get_status() != 'refunded') &&        ($order->get_status() != 'failed'))